# How to use ui-grid with ng-repeat and angular-ui.bootstrap.collapse

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat, ui-grid

I have a table where I use *ng-repeat* and *angular-ui collapse* to show data on it. I would like to implement *ui-grid*, but I'm not even near a solution.

Here's a Plunker of my code: https://plnkr.co/edit/mKeRaDv22WzBXjRT67oO?p=preview

The html code:

```
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 20%">A: </th>
          <th style="width: 20%">B: </th>
          <th style="width: 15%">C: </th>
          <th style="width: 15%">D: </th>
          <th style="width: 15%">E: </th>
          <th style="width: 15%">F: </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody ng-repeat="data in myData" ng-click="element.isCollapsed = !element.isCollapsed">
        <tr>
          <td>{{data.a}}</td>
          <td>{{data.b}}</td>
          <td>{{data.c}}</td>
          <td>{{data.d}}</td>
          <td>{{data.e}}</td>
          <td>{{data.f}}</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr collapse="element.isCollapsed" ng-show="element.isCollapsed">
          <td colspan="2">{{data.g}} </td>
          <td colspan="2">{{data.h}} </td>
          <td colspan="2">{{data.i}} </td>
        </tr>
        <tr collapse="element.isCollapsed" ng-show="element.isCollapsed">
          <td colspan="2">{{data.j}} </td>
          <td colspan="2">{{data.k}} </td>
          <td colspan="2">{{data.l}} </td>
        </tr>
        <tr collapse="element.isCollapsed" ng-show="element.isCollapsed">
          <td colspan="6">{{data.m}} </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```